# Bash shell script expression and condition syntax

Tags: bash, shell, unix

While going through project config files, I come across shell scripts and which I fail to understand.
The script is something like this-

```
#list all possible environments
env="local,dev,qa";

# check valid environment.
if [[ ",$env," != *",$ENV,"* ]] ; then
    echo "ENVIRONMENT is $ENV but must be set to local, dev or qa as per the environment.";
    exit 1;
fi
```

Here how the if condition gets evaluated and what does it mean?

also while running it shows error : [[: not found

Comment: See https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/testconstructs.html

Comment: @oguzismail, please don't encourage folks to use the ABS -- it's notorious for using bad practices in its examples, so folks can easily pick up unfortunate habits when trying to follow it. [BashFAQ #31](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031) is a better reference on the topic. The bash-hackers' wiki also has good docs on [the conditional expression](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/conditional_expression) and [the classic `test` command](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/classictest).

Comment: BTW, the environment variable name `ENV` is actually reserved to be meaningful *to the shell*, as the name of a script to be executed when even a noninteractive POSIX-compliant shell starts up (compare to `.bashrc`, which only runs for *interactive* shells). Yes, there are tools that rely on `ENV` being meaningful, but those tools are poorly-specified for that reason. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, reserving names with at least one lower-case character for application use and calling out ENV as reserved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Condition* syntax in `bash` starts with:

`if` *command*

The `[[` is actually a command (there is also `[` and `((`).

```
$ type [[
[[ is a shell keyword
```

The condition test inside `[[` is rather strange:

```
",$env," != *",$ENV,"*
```

The `$env` and `$ENV` represent the *values* of variables `env` and `ENV` respectively.  The `*` on the right mean "zero or more of any character". `!=` means "not equal to", although here it indicates "does not match".
The quotes around the variable are to prevent any special characters (like *)  in the value from being expanded by the shell.  The commas are just literal characters.

Quite why the programmer didn't just say `"$env" != "$ENV"` I'm not sure, but don't fix it if it ain't broke.

`ENV` is a special variable used to determine the name of a start-up file when the shell is invoked using `sh` rather than `bash`.  The implication is that in this script it is mis-used.

Why are you getting `error : [[: not found`?  Please show exactly how you ran this script, because it implies you are not using `bash` or `sh`.  For example, if you use `csh` (C-shell) then you get:

```
% [[
[[: Command not found.
```

which is similar, but not exactly the same as the error message you show.

Comment: Good answer! A small detail, the `((` is not a command, but an (arithmetic) expansion, so it's similar to `$variable` or `~` expansions.

Comment: @KamilCuk:  yes, you are right  The `bash` man pages actually say `if` *list*, but I felt *command* was more descriptive.

Comment: The error message "[[: not found" is consistent with the script being run under dash (rather than bash).

Comment: `[[` isn't guaranteed to be present in POSIX sh -- one doesn't need to go nearly as far as csh to find somewhere it's missing.

Comment: Re: "quite why the programmer didn't just say `"$env" != "$ENV"`", btw -- the idiom used in the original code allows `env` to be a comma-separated list. Think `env=one,two,three; ENV=two`.

Comment: The error message makes it sound like `env` is the list of acceptable values, and `ENV` has to be exactly *one* of `local`, `dev`, or `qa`. A case statement would have been much more appropriate (and POSIX-compatible to boot): `case $ENV in local|dev|qa) ;; *) echo "Error!"; exit 1; ;; esac`. The original *is* broken, and it should be fixed.

Comment: The reason for my comment "don't fix it if it ain't broke" is that the OP is *looking* at someone else's code, and is clearly a beginner.    The code might be flawed but it needs to be understood before the OP starts hacking it around.  We all know that well-intentioned fixes can create more problems than they solve when done badly.